# Why does Github use machine's time while pushing?

Tags: git, github

I noticed that Github uses the time of the local machine while pushing code. So, suppose if a person's PC's time is 6 hours back and he pushes a change the branch's latest update time will show as 6 hours ago on the project's page on Github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with GitHub at all.

The `commit` operation of `git` records the local time that the changeset was created, as it's a completely local operation not involving anyone else than the commiting user and computer.

All what the `push` operation of `git` does is to copy changesets between related repositories, while keeping all their metadata intact. The fact that GitHub is involved is irrelevant until now.

What GitHub does is to provide a `git` server and a nice web interface to it, but that's all. GitHub has no way to know when the commit was really created. It does know when it was pushed to it, but changing the date to reflect that is certainly not expected by clients, because that's not how `git` works.

This is, not coincidentally, the very same thing that happens in *any* `git` repository (once again GitHub has nothing to do in this question). Moreover, other DVCSs also exhibit the same thing. On centralized VCSs, on the other hand, the commit is created directly in the server, and that's the date reflected, not the local one, because there is only one repository, the central one, and clients only hold working copies.